# What's the grouping plan so that every two people are grouped together just once?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

So, we have N people.

Everyday, we make N/2 groups out of them, i.e., 2 people are in one group.

We keep grouping everyday, until every two people have been paired exactly once, no more no less.

Please give the grouping plan for every day.

---

Here are my thoughts:

Out of N people, there are `N * (N-1) / 2` possible pairs. Since everyday we will have `N/2` pairs, totally we will need `N-1` days.

So basically, if our algorithm takes a list of N people as input, we will output `N-1` lists, each list will contain the pairs for a day.

---

But how to organise these `N * (N-1) / 2` pairs into `N-1` days?

I know how to do it in a bruteforce way, like worst case, we try every combinations of pairs for every day, or better use hashtset to see whether a combination for a day is possible or not (a hashset for a day).

But I think there must be a more elegant and efficient way to solve the problem. Graph?

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ it is correct as number pairs is NC2 which is N(N-1)/2

Comment: @VikramBhat Yep, it's the same :) I was aware of that common simplification, just had to think it through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm - This seems to answer your question. I have also seen this discussed in the context of chess matches and bond settlements.

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for additional reference. If you're not up to this task, you should consider simply leaving a comment on the question instead of posting an answer.